# cat | dd pipe causes partial reads without iflag=fullblock, why truncated to 128KiB?

Tags: pipe, dd, cat

Consider this sample 1MiB file:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=input.img bs=1M count=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1048576 bytes (1.0 MB, 1.0 MiB) copied, 0.00100595 s, 1.0 GB/s
```

If I try to `cat` it and pipe it into `dd` without using `iflag=fullblock` I can't read more than 128KiB per block:

```
$ cat input.img | dd of=output.img bs=128k count=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
131072 bytes (131 kB, 128 KiB) copied, 0.000221117 s, 593 MB/s
```

```
$ cat input.img | dd of=output.img bs=129k count=1
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
131072 bytes (131 kB, 128 KiB) copied, 0.000495317 s, 265 MB/s
```

```
$ cat input.img | dd of=output.img bs=1M count=1
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
131072 bytes (131 kB, 128 KiB) copied, 0.000437209 s, 300 MB/s
```

Using 2 block counts it even prints a warning:

```
$ cat input.img | dd of=output.img bs=129k count=2
dd: warning: partial read (131072 bytes); suggest iflag=fullblock
0+2 records in
0+2 records out
262144 bytes (262 kB, 256 KiB) copied, 0.00107657 s, 243 MB/s
```

I thought it could be due to the pipe buffer size, however I checked its size following https://www.golinuxhub.com/2018/05/how-to-view-and-increase-default-pipe-size-buffer.html and it seems set to 65536 bytes:

```
$ mkfifo /tmp/testfifo
$ python2
>>> fifo_fd = open('/tmp/testfifo', 'rb+')
>>> import fcntl
>>> fcntl.fcntl(fifo_fd, 1032)
65536
```

(Note I couldn't make it work with Python3 I guess because of https://bugs.python.org/issue20074)

The main question is (pure curiosity): why do reads get truncated to 128KiB?

(Tested on Arch Linux, kernel 5.4.2, zsh 5.7.1.)

Comment: You have creatively interpreted the article you link to: what you're doing in your `python` snippet is trying to set the pipe size to its minimum value with `fcntl(fifo_fd, F_SETPIPE_SZ, 0)`. If you want to get the default value, you should use `fcnt(fifo_fd, F_GETPIPE_SZ)`. The default value is most certainly 65536, but it could be increased up to the value in `/proc/sys/fs/pipe-max-size`.

Comment: As to why `dd` reads chunks of 128k bytes when you asked it for 129k, it's because a `read(.., 129k)` returned 128k. There's no guarantee whatsoever that a read won't return a shorter count than asked, and it's not a reasonable assumption than it will only rarely do that. The `dd` manpage says about the `bs=BYTES` argument: "read and write __up to__ BYTES bytes", not "exactly BYTES bytes".

Comment: @mosvy your claim is not correct, see what I posted 2 hours before you posted your comment. 128k is read because the program `gcat` only writes 128k and not more.

Comment: @schily What claim is not correct? I've strace-d the OP's testcase, and it says `read(0, ..., 132096) = 131072`. And the second part is a literal quote from the `dd(1)` manpage.

Comment: What do you expect from this test? The question was why it is not able to return **more** than 128k and this is of course a result from the `write()` size used by `gcat`.

Comment: @schily so what is my incorrect claim?

Comment: To assume that the read size of 128k is the limiting factor. It is rather the write size used by `gcat`.

Comment: @schily So there's no incorrect claim whatsoever, it's just you making assumptions about what I'm supposed to assume.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any block size greater then `PIPE_BUF` (5k on modern UNIX, 4k on Linux) is not granted to pass a pipe without fragementation.

This means, it **may** be split, but there is no grant for a split.

Whether you are able to read more than `PIPE_BUF` at all depends on the memory state of the kernel that controls when the write side is stopped by the kernel to prevent it from eating all kernel memory. It also depends on the timing and scheduling of the read side and whether it gets a wakeup after a sufficient amount of data has been accumulated.

BTW: A `dd` option named `iflag=fullblock` is a vendor specific extension. Avoid to use it since it is non-standard.

Also note that `gcat` uses a write block size of 128k, while the UNIX version of `cat` is `mmap()` based and uses a write size of `8Mbyte`. So if you did run this test on a genetic UNIX, you could be able to read larger blocks than 128k,

Comment: fullblock may be a vendor-specific extension, but it is supported by a lot of vendors: GNU dd, Busybox dd, and Toybox dd all support `iflag=fullblock` - do you know of a modern dd which doesn't support it?